# Why is Amrita 'bad luck for the big guys'?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

In *Avatar The Way of Water* (2022), Scoresby extracted Amrita from Tulkun brain:

> Scoresby: Amrita. **Bad luck for the big guys**.
> This stuff just happens to stop human aging. Like...
> stops it.

Why is Amrita bad luck for the big guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said in your question, the substance known as 'amrita' is an [anti-agathic](https://fancyclopedia.org/Anti-agathic) hence pretty much priceless to people living on Earth.

Unfortunately for the 'big guys' (e.g. the tulkuns) this substance can only be harvested by **killing them and chopping out their brains.**

> The RDA have set their sights on the tulkun after the discovery of a
> naturally occurring substance in the creature’s brains known as
> amrita. The substance has the medical power to stop human aging. Since
> this discovery, the RDA have deployed tulkun hunting squads to capture
> and harvest the material.
>
> <sub><sup>https://www.avatar.com/pandorapedia/tulkun</sup></sub>